# BeautifulSoup & Selenium - not extracting full html from webpage

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, urllib3

Using either sections of code below, neither pulls all the divs from the webpage. 
Both return a NoneType for content. This also happens for `{"id": "image_wrap"}` and others. Which shows it is not extracting the full HTML. (I have written data to .html documents to check as well)

However, other webpages such as http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/390693 successfully download the full html. It is just certain URLs that do this, other works completely fine. It does not seem to be a javascript issue as the same happens when using selenium.

```
import bs4
import urllib3

url = "http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/390695"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', url)
html = response.data
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
content = soup.find("div", {"id": "image_wrap"})
print(content)
```

Below is using selenium to dynamically load the webpage.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4

url = "http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/390695"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
content = soup.find("div", {"id": "image_wrap"})
print(content)
```

Why is this only happening for certain URLs?

Comment: Is this happen always for the same urls ? If yes then add those urls in question.

Comment: Yes but i've been parsing thousands so posting them all would be irrelevant, the ones that always work always work and vice versa. Which is why i've given one example of each

Comment: But show some url so we could see its HTML

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that in code is different url.

Comment: I downloaded `http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/390695` and there is no `div` with `id=image_wrap` - so sever generates page without this element and you have to ask server admin why it generates crappy HTML.

Comment: No problem. So on the URLs where this happens, I won't be able to get the data as it is a fault on their side? Also if the server generates the page without this element, how does it still display on the page?

Comment: I checked other pages and all pages with single image don't have this "ID". Maybe users may choose different options or templates and then pages look different and use different tags.

Comment: This is only `<div>` tag. Image is in `<img>` tag so why shouldn't display it ?

Comment: Oh true, apologies new to HTML parsing. Thank you for your help. How did you see these pages only had a single image?

Comment: I opened both your urls in browser and then I clicked on links to other "Related Posts" and using DevTool in browser I was checking "image_wrap" on all pages. If page didn't have this ID then I was looking on page to see how different it is then other pages. And I see some pages have only single image, other two or even more (http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/390685). Some pages have arrows to next page, other have button "Buy This" (http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/822064). It seems pages may use different templates so you will need different methods to search data.

Comment: Have you tried putting some delay just after `browser.get(url)`?